# How can i update store page load first time react hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I just a newbie react hook so i have a case like this:

```
const [lessonStore, updateLessonStore] = useLessonStore();
const fetchLessons = async () => {
   updateLessonStore(draft => {
       draft.filter = {
       limit: TABLE.defaultLimit,
       page: 1,
       courses: values,
     };
   });
   console.log(lessonStore)  
   const res = await getLessons(lessonStore.filter);
   if (res) {
     switch (res.status) {
      case httpStatus.OK: {
       setData(res.data);
       break;
     }
      case httpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED: {
       resetRefreshTokenFailure();
       break;
      }
      default:
       break;
      }
     }
   };
useEffect(() => {
  fetchLessons();
  }, [lessonStore.filter.limit, lessonStore.filter.page,lessonStore.filter.courses]);
```

I have two question and I hope anyone can explain:

- In the console.log, why courses in the lessonStore don't have values ? (values are array id)
- How to at lessonStore.filter.courses in useEffect not render infinite loop ?

Sorry for my bad english and thank you.

Comment: Could we tell more about: Where the `values` comes from? and example of `lessonStore `

Answer (score 0):

**In the console.log, why courses in the lessonStore don't have values ? (values are array id)**

- State updates are asynchronous. The `fetchLessons` value is being derived from closure(i.e. previous value).

**How to at lessonStore.filter.courses in useEffect not render infinite loop ?**

- The useEffect executes when `lessonStore.filter.courses` plus other dependencies are changed. Inside useEffect, you are updating the `lessonStore.filter.courses` and hence you end up with infinite loop. You can remove `lessonStore.filter.courses` from the dependency array.

Comment: tks @gdh, but how i at values to courses at first time load ??

Comment: not exactly sure what you are asking but to run the effect only 1 time on page load you need to pass in an empty array as the second argument so change [lessonStore.filter.limit, lessonStore.filter.page,lessonStore.filter.courses]  to []